# Tmux: Unzoom pane when switching to another pane

Tags: tmux

In tmux, `prefix + z` toggles the active pane between zoomed / unzoomed. Also, the tmux-pain-control plugin allows moving to another pane (same window) with `prefix + i/j/k/l`. 
Now, when from a zoomed pane, I would like to be able to unzoom *and* move with only `prefix + i/j/k/l` rather than `prefix + x` and then `prefix + i/j/k/l`.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried remapping `prefix + i` to `resize-pane -Z \; select-pane -L` but in vain...